# Kafka topic cannot be deleted or recreated

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-topic

I have a Kafka topic that seems to simultaneously exist and not exist.

```
kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic my-topic --delete
```

returns an error:

```
Topics in [] does not exist
```

Meanwhile, trying to re-create the topic

```
kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic my-topic \
 --create --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1
```

returns

```
Topic already exists
```

It does not show up in the topics list with

```
kafka-topics.sh --list
```

I suspect some form of corruption but it's no clear how I can fully delete the topic so that it can be re-created

Comment: Can you plase share the full commands you have used? Also, how many brokers does your cluster have?

Comment: updated with full command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing `--bootstrap-server` try with `--zookeeper`

---

```
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic my-topic --delete
```

Comment: @wrschneider You are supposed to provide the Zookeeper Host and not the Kafka brokers.

Comment: I had a similar problem, running into `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Topic 'x' does not exist as expected` errors while deleting. Your answer helped me finding the root cause, thanks!

Comment: there is no "zookeeper" option in newer versions